# Can't open web application from cloud

Tags: visual-studio, iis

I have started a web application on my computer.
Then I move it to OneDrive so I can access it from my desktop.
But when I´m opening the application on the desktop it says:

[image: Picture of my error message]

And in the solution it looks like this:

[image: Picture of the solution]

Comment: It is very bad idea to store your source code in OneDrive that way. Consider other alternatives please.

Comment: Agreed. If you want to share code between machines, it's probably wise to check out Git. If you want free private Git hosting for your own code, check out Visual Studio Team Services.